# In what situations is it a crime to provide an [EDIT: Image of possibly non-existent] fake or altered US gov't ID in digital form to a company

Tags: united-states, criminal-law

In particular, were a company to require (perhaps unreasonably) a copy of some kind of government identification, such as a Driver's License, is it illegal to produce a fake digital image of an identification document?

I have seen this answer: [Is it legal to submit fake digital identification documents to private companies?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/is-it-legal-to-submit-fake-digital-identification-documents-to-private-companies)

But it was not clear to me what the definition of 'fake identification document' is. Would an image depicting a 'supposed' (but non-existent) identification document constitute an identification document? My understanding is that producing such an image and sending it (digitally) is not a crime. However I suspect this is incorrect and has been covered/clarified somewhere, so hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I do notice that the answer to the above question cites a section that refers to a definition of identification document:

> (3)the term “identification document” means a document made or issued by or under the authority of the United States Government, a State, political subdivision of a State, a sponsoring entity of an event designated as a special event of national significance, a foreign government, political subdivision of a foreign government, an international governmental or an international quasi-governmental organization which, when completed with information concerning a particular individual, is of a type intended or commonly accepted for the purpose of identification of individuals;

And furthermore,

> (4)the term “false identification document” means a document of a type intended or commonly accepted for the purposes of identification of individuals that— (A)is not issued by or under the authority of a governmental entity or was issued under the authority of a governmental entity but was subsequently altered for purposes of deceit; and (B)appears to be issued by or under the authority of the United States Government, a State, a political subdivision of a State, a sponsoring entity of an event designated by the President as a special event of national significance, a foreign government, a political subdivision of a foreign government, or an international governmental or quasi-governmental organization;

I do not know much about law, so it is not clear to me whether a digital image depicting an identification document is considered an identification document; and for example, whether such an image would be "of a type intended or commonly accepted for the purposes of identification of individuals", since it is an image and not an actual identification document. For example, such an image would not be sufficient for retailers bound to verify ID (e.g. liquor), DMV and various commercial entities entrusted to issue automotive registration documents, police officers, TSA agents, CBP agents, etc; in those situations (which surely comprise the majority of the possible identification-verification scenarios), such a digital image is not "intended or commonly accepted for the purposes of identification of individuals".

Thanks

Edit 
Some clarification to make this question and my motivation clearer. 
The prototypical example (and what got me thinking of this) was a friend of mine who made a purchase of a few hundred dollars at an online clothing retailer located outside of the US. After the purchase, the retailer followed up indicating they required a scan/fax of driver's license, and some other piece of information I forgot. She did not send it (so the transaction was cancelled), since it would be inadvisable to send such a piece of information not only over email (which is likely, though not necessarily secure) and into an organization with unknown data-handling practices, in another country, etc.

With this example in mind, I am curious as to whether it would be legal to create and submit an *image of/depicting a non-existent identification document*, to a company, perhaps such a company as I have cited. Whether this constitutes a false ID document is not clear, except for example in the case of Virginia which was highlighted by a contributor below, since Virginia considers a false 'facsimile' of the ID document to be a false ID document and therefore illegal.

It has been claimed in the comments that this would be fraud, but I unfortunately do not know what a definitive definition of fraud would be as it applies to this situation. The definition of fraud I read is from Wikipedia:

> In law, fraud is deliberate deception to secure unfair or unlawful gain, or to deprive a victim of a legal right.

it is not clear to me whether, for example in the clothing retailer example, the individual who transmits the image depicting the non-existent ID is securing an unfair or unlawful gain. Perhaps the retailer is being deprived of a legal right, but I am not certain.

Comment: That question has a general US answer because it hinges on falsifying a US passport. What you are proposing presumably involves a state document. The general answer is "it is fraud", so we don't need to know about "identification documents". If you pick a state (that's how fraud laws are constructed), we can show why the act would be fraud. Or I could pick my favorite state.

Comment: What if there is no 'unlawful gain' etc that I understand to be the defining feature of fraud. What if it's just the example in that other question, where it's just a free Facebook account? Or if an online clothing retailer decides they need your driver's license to process a transaction? Presumably there has been no unlawful / unfair gain, or damage to the other party, in these cases.

Comment: If there is nothing to gain from submitting the false document, then why would you do it?

Comment: In the hypothetical scenarios I have in mind, one would do it for example to maintain privacy, prevent sensitive data (e.g. license numbers) from being handled by some company that does not necessarily have a sound policy implemented for handling and disposing of such data (or maybe it is a requirement- still). Certainly one gains from such an act but I don't know how to describe it as 'unlawful', or to distinguish any (tenuous, surely) loss on the part of the other party from other things which are certainly not illegal such as providing false names, addresses, etc.

Comment: It seems that I should be making a precision about the sorts of companies I am thinking of, but unfortunately my knowledge does not extend that far. I am thinking of companies which do not necessarily, "over the course of their work" require identification to ensure the "legal integrity" of their business interaction, whether required by law or otherwise. Examples of companies I am not thinking of include insurance companies and financial services companies, latter of which may be required to verify identity under anti-terrorism laws for example

Comment: And even among those companies which could be said to require the ID to ensure the "legal integrity of their business practice", I would say it is preferable to provide false documents to say an online clothing retailer which, it could be said is requiring identification to protect against loss from card fraud claims (illegal activity). So I would include such scenarios among those I have in mind. While the production and submission of an image depicting a false document is dubious, I do not see that the company would be harmed from such an act (this is my limited understanding of 'fraud')

Comment: A company cannot randomly demand that you provide documentation: they do that *in exchange for something*. That is the thing that you would be fraudulently getting. For example, employment; using their services; acquiring their products.

Comment: Not sure if it makes sense to me. If a company demands info such as name, street address, email, etc, and one provides false information, has one fraudulently used their services? And that is in a scenario where the company requires such information at all times for all services. In the scenarios I am considering, it's not necessarily the case that the company requires the information always when rendering the service; so I'm not sure if you get the service 'in exchange for' the ID verification. It may be the case that the verification is a countermeasure for certain cases.

Comment: And again, even if one is getting something in exchange, I do not see why it would be 'fraudulent'; I don't see why such gain would be unlawful, or harm the other party (in most cases- take the online clothing retailer as example). The unlawful nature of such a gain would presumably depend on a determination of the use of the false identification as being unlawful, in which case we don't need to consider fraud in the first place, i.e. the use of the false ID is unlawful in and of itself independently of any fraud..

Comment: @A__A__0: The use of the false ID is fraud in itself. You are presenting, and representing as true, information you know to be false, in order to obtain something that you would not have gotten without that info. That's the very definition of theft by deception (ie: fraud).
And in VA, for example, the mere _possession_ of a fake government-issued identification document, _or any facsimile thereof_, is a class 2 misdemeanor (punishable by up to 6 months in jail). Production of such a facsimile ups the crime to a class 1 misdemeanor.

Comment: I see your point about VA, thanks. I suppose in some states the facsimile portion is not included? In which case the ambiguity about such an image remains. Also, without the facsimile condition, I still don't see how it is fraud, since presumably the criteria you mention would apply if one provides any false information in such a scenario, such as false name and address; based on the definition I read (just the wikipedia synopsis), it would need to be an illegal use of such information (sending/possessing the facsimile in VA for example), for it to be fraud.

Comment: I apologize if the discussion has become too lengthy or technical. I'm not familiar with how technical an argument usually is in law, or whether it's inappropriate for analysis to be as technically sound as I seem to be demanding. Maybe a court would "just determine it is illegal" and it would be a conviction.

Comment: Some states are more strict than others, yes...but any ambiguity you rely on probably won't be there for long. Win a case involving an image of a fake ID, and watch how fast "facsimiles" become illegal. If, when presenting your faked image of an ID to someone, _you told them it's not your real ID_, then you probably wouldn't be committing fraud per se. But of course you're not going to do that in general -- precisely because the point of forging an ID in the first place is to deceive. (And BTW, yes, knowingly providing a false name or address can be fraud as well.)

Comment: I would not say that in general the point of sending an image depicting a non-existent ID is necessarily to deceive. In the cases I have in mind, one goal is to protect privacy and prevent the leakage of sensitive information. I will update my question so that it is clearer and more focused. In any case, based on the definition of fraud that I read, I do not see that sending such an image would be fraud unless (for example in VA) the possession/transmission of the image is illegal in itself.

Comment: Also, I understand that providing false name/address can be fraud (I assume insurance would be an example). I brought up this example as a contradiction implied by the statement that providing false ID is fraud in general, which I understand you to have claimed. Providing a false name or address to Facebook or some other free website for example is presumably not fraud.

Comment: All US states have "electronic form" laws that prevent one from repudiating a document offered against you merely because you supplied it to them in "electronic form", including via "facsimile" and an "electronic signature", as variously defined.

Comment: @Upnorth I see, by "document offered against you"  you mean a document in court which is offered as evidence that a crime was committed? So such equivalences will make the fabrication of the 'facsimile' (here, the image depicting the non-existent ID) illegal? (illegal because it would consequently be considered equivalent to a fake ID in the courtroom)

Comment: I didn't say anything about "equivalence." No, the legal status of a document offered as evidence in court really has little to do with one being offered as a forgery in commerce, although perjured evidence is also a felony.

Comment: @Upnorth I see. Sorry, I don't really understand how it relates. Is the image depicting the non-existent ID illegal to fabricate / possess? Is it illegal to send to a company, particularly the one I cited as a prototypical example? If so why?